# Port forwarding with ssh where the final destination does not have sshd running

Tags: ssh

I know how to use ssh to port forward a local port say like 7000 to a remote ssh server on port 50070. For example:

```
ssh -L 7000:127.0.01:50070 root@sshserver
```

"Me port 7000" - > "ssherver port 50070"

But now say I have my "sshserver" at the office and I want to port forward my local port via the "sshserver" to the windows machine that has terminal services running on port 3389. To clarify the windows machine does not have sshd running.

"Me port 7000" - > "sshserver" - > "windows machine port 3389"

Is this possible with ssh?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking, but the ssh port forwarding is just a generic TCP forwarder. Any TCP connection can be established over the forwarded link, not just ssh. As long as the Windows machine port 3389 is a TCP service the forward should work.

Comment: How do I make the tcp connection to the windows server?

Comment: By connecting to your local port 7000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local port forwarding means forwarding a port on the SSH client machine *through* the SSH server machine, not *onto* it.  The IP address you specify in the argument is *any* address/hostname reachable from you SSH server.  Thus if the Wintendo box is behind the server you are able to SSH into, and reachable from it, you simply can do this on your client:

```
$ ssh -L 7000:<IP of Windows box>:3389 <SSH server>
```

Then you can connect to your client's port 7000 and the connection is forwarded through your SSH server to the Windows box's port 3389.

Comment: I thought that I usually put 127.0.0.1 / localhost was just for the interface to listen on now I learned it can really be anything. Thank you!